# Vue + vue-i18n: ссылка в переводимом тексте

Tags: vue.js

В проекте на вью для локализации использую библиотеку vue-i18n. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать так, чтобы ссылка в тексте оповещения отрисовывалась как элемент и это была рабочая ссылка при условии, что `path` не постоянен (динамически меняется, `notification` берётся из состояния).

Если не биндить `path` и просто руками вписать туда ключ от конкретной строки (`path="errorY"`), например, то работает: ссылка отрисовывается и кликается. Но это мне не подходит. И в некоторых оповещениях мне нужна ссылка, а в некоторых нет.

Ниже мой текущий код. Так вместо ссылки ничего не отрисовывается вообще (см. картинку, элемента ссылки там тоже нет).
[image: notification-without-link]

```
  <i18n :path="notification.text" tag="p" class="text">
    <template #link>
      <a href="https://my.link" target="_blank">{{ $t('linkText') }}</a>
    </template>
  </i18n>
```

В файле со строками:

```
"errorX": "Server side error! Error code: {error}.",
"errorY": "Failed to connect! Follow these {link}. Error code: {error}."
"linkText": "instructions"
```

Где-то в коде, где обрабатывается ошибка:

```
catch (error) {
  this.$store.dispatch("notify", {
    type: "error",
    text: this.$t("errorY", { error })
  });
}
```

Если ссылку передавать здесь (т.е. так же, как `error`), она отрисовывается, как строка.
[image: notification-ugly-link]

Делалось по вот [этому](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#slots-syntax-usage) гайду.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Вы имеете в виду картинки с текстом оповещений? Спасибо, я как-то не расценила их как текст, подумала, что скриншоты нагляднее. Буду знать!

Comment: Второй вариант точно можно вывести через директиву `v-html`, если просто в строку с переводом задать код и подстановкой менять. А вот почему первый вариант не работает — вопрос, конечно, интересный.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, спасибо, что напомнили о `v-html`) Но да, этот вариант, к сожалению, мне не подходит.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, спасибо большое за подсказку! Перечитала ваше сообщение и осознала, что в первый раз немного не так его поняла. Всё-таки `v-html` стал выходом.

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря подсказкам в комментариях к вопросу, нашла решение для своей задачи. Её можно решить, используя не компонент `i18n` и слоты, а с помощью обычных элементов и директивы `v-html`. Т.к. в моём случае используются только "свои" строки, а не что-то предоставляемое пользователем или откуда-то ещё извне, это безопасно.

```
<p class="text" v-html="$t(notification.text)"></p>
```

Код ссылки теперь находится в строке, а код в блоке обработки ошибки остался неизменным.

```
"errorY": "Failed to connect! Follow these <a href='https://my.link' target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>instructions</a>. Error code: {error}."
```

Кроме того, нашёлся [пример](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/formatting.html#html-formatting) в гайде по библиотеке vue-i18n, где приводится такое же решение. Но автор опять же указывает: *Only use HTML interpolation on trusted content and never on user-provided content.*